# ¿Cómo realizar un filtrado de búsqueda en MongoDB limitando número de caracteres del campo a buscar?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo un campo en MongoDB Compass (`cliente`), que es número de cliente, necesito saber cómo realizar un filtrado de búsqueda en MongoDB Compass que el límite de caracteres sea de diferente de 8

Ejemplo de query sql:

```
 len(cast (cliente as varchar))<> 8
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr para que quede más claro.

Comment: Cómo buscar este ejemplo de query sql en Mongodb Compass ... SELECT * FROM tienda where   cliente not in(90001)  and len(cast (cliente as varchar))<> 8

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y agrega detalles a tu pregunta, por ejemplo: *tipo de campo (string, number, objectid)* sobre el cual harás la consulta, y si es posible un ejemplo del documento. Te sugiero también que uses la terminología adecuada, [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/es/products/compass) es una solución de UI para realizar operaciones sobre MongoDB, por lo tanto ***el campo no pertenece a Compass***, pertenece a un documento de una colección en alguna base de datos de MongoDB. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
db.tienda.find({ 
    //En caso de que haya documentos sin el campo cliente, 
    // (cosa que no defines) revisamos si existe.  
    "cliente": { "$exists": true },
    //Permite el uso de expresiones de agregación dentro del lenguaje de consulta.
    "$expr": {
         //Debe ser difenerte
         "$neq": [
                //strLenCp Devuelve el número de puntos de código UTF-8 en la cadena especificada.
                { "$strLenCP": "$cliente" }, 8
         ] 
    } 
})
```

Tomado de [esta respueta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29578020/4326551).